# Cmsplugin-Nivoslider plugin for Django-CMS

Tags: django, plugins, django-cms, nivo-slider

I am new to Django-CMS, I have successfully installed Django-CMS on my Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit OS). I want to add Nivo Slider on my web page using Cmsplugin-Nivoslider. After following steps mention in https://bitbucket.org/bercab/cmsplugin-nivoslider/overview, I am able to install cmsplugin-nivoslider on my Django-CMS. After syncdb, migrate and collectstatic commands, I am able to see nivo folder with js, theme and css files in my static folder, but I am not able to see anything on my Admin Panel related to Nivo Slider. Please tell me, do I need to do any further steps to use nivo-slider, How can I put that slider on my page ? Please guide me..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Admin interface, Add or edit a Page, you should have available a plugin for slider if the chosen template has a block &/or placeholder tag. Configure gallery from there.